# Is it ok to directly overwrite Dataflow template parameters that are set at build-time?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

We would like to prevent certain parameters (namely filesToStage) of our Dataflow template from populating in the Dataflow Job page. Is there a recommended way to achieve this? We've found that simply specifying `"filesToStage="` when launching the template via `gcloud` suffices, but we're not sure if this is robust/stable behavior.

For context, we are hosting this Dataflow template for customer usage and would like to hide as much of the implementation as possible (including classpaths).

Comment: Tlaquetzal's answer is correct: essentially, you should not be overriding values. For filesToStage, you can produce an uberjar for all of your classes, and that way you can avoid showing the specific packages you're staging. In general, though, you probably want a more customizable view of Dataflow, and that sounds like a reasonable feature request

Comment: would you be willing to send a feature request to Dataflow?

Comment: Sure, let's talk outside of SO.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically the `filesToStage` can be sent as blank and the files will be inferred based on the Java classpath:

> If filesToStage is blank, Dataflow will infer the files to stage based on the Java classpath.

More information on the considerations for this and other fields can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/specifying-exec-params#setting-other-cloud-dataflow-pipeline-options).

For other parameters, the [recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49580830/7517757) is to use [Cloud KMS](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/overview) to keep the parameters hidden.

Comment: By blank, do you mean explicitly setting `filesToStage=`, or omitting it entirely? The first does not work (no JARs are staged), and the second is what I was doing before. It seems as if Dataflow is setting that parameter for me when it infers the files to stage. I think Pablo's idea about the Uber JAR is the easiest resolution for now.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Yes, if you specify "filesToStage=" you will explicitly remove all the files, which won't work. I was referring to omit the parameter,; however, that wouldn't fix the visibility concern. I think @Pablo suggestion is the way to go for filesToStage and the Cloud KMS can be used for other parameters.

Comment: Also, [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187168&template=0) you can create a Feature Request to the Dataflow team, asking to provide options to hide the parameters from the Job UI